# Creating an N-Dimensional array of type T and populating it

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting

I am currently working on a small system where I will read certain values from a `byte` array. One of the types must be an array. The other types are primitives and strings.

The problem I am having is trying to create the and populate the array. The array gets populated from a method, lets call it `next()`. `next()` will return a non-null `Object` - this object will not be an array. The length is also dynamic and is loaded from another source, but for the following code it will merely be provided.

```
final Integer[][] array = readArray(Integer[][].class, 10);
//... 

// T = Integer[][]
// S = Integer[]
public static <T, S> S[] readArray(final Class<T> cls, final int length) {
    if (cls.isArray()) {
        final Class<S> subCls = (Class<S>) cls.getComponentType();
        final S[] array = (S[]) Array.newInstance(subCls, length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (subCls.isArray()) {
                array[i] = readArray(subCls, length);
            } else {
                array[i] = (S) next();
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type of cls must be an array.");
}
```

So far, I have this. The problem at the moment is with the line:

```
array[i] = readArray(subCls, length);
```

The error is:

```
Error:(28, 41) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T,S exist so that S[] conforms to S
```

I've tried many ways around this. Including using a `HelperArray<T, S>` class, but even that did not work.

I would also like to point out that the type of the array may not be guaranteed. The only real guarantee is that the top-level component types for the array will either be a string or a primitive.  For example, the following could very well happen:

```
Object[][]{String[]{}, Integer[]{}, byte[]{}}
```

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: is `newArray` something you defined?  It's a little hard to tell what is going on here.

Comment: @Gian thanks for point that out. Renamed it for a separate test case. What needs to be clarified?

Comment: I see, this is a very sophisticated problem you have here. Have you tried skippaing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cobbled this together, does that help you?

For me the output is a 10x10 2D array with all ones.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] array = readArray(Integer[][].class, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + ",");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // T = Integer[][]
    // S = Integer[]
    public static <T, S> S[] readArray(final Class<T> cls, final int length) {
        if (cls.isArray()) {
            final Class<S> subCls = (Class<S>) cls.getComponentType();
            final S[] array = (S[]) Array.newInstance(subCls, length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (subCls.isArray()) {
                    array[i] = (S) readArray((Class<?>) subCls, length);
                } else {
                    array[i] = (S) next();
                }
            }
            return array;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type of cls must be an array.");
    }

    private static Object next() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, got it to work. Going to kill myself in 3 years when the legacy code breaks and I have to rewrite this, but I'll deal with that in the future. Technically, @Icewind was correct in his answer - I just forgot to account for primitives which made the problem - literally - exponentially harder.

**Warning: Code Gore Ahead [NSFW]**

```
public synchronized <T, S> T readArray(final Class<T> cls) {
    if (next() != IDENTIFIER_ARRAY) {
        throw new InvalidProtocolException(lastReadIndex);
    }
    final int nextID = next();
    final int length = readRawInt();
    final Class<S> component = (Class<S>) cls.getComponentType();
    if (component.isPrimitive()) {
        switch (component.getCanonicalName()) {
            case "boolean":
                return (T) readRawBooleanArray(length);
            case "byte":
                return (T) readRawByteArray(length);
            case "short":
                return (T) readRawShortArray(length);
            case "char":
                return (T) readRawCharArray(length);
            case "int":
                return (T) readRawIntArray(length);
            case "float":
                return (T) readRawFloatArray(length);
            case "long":
                return (T) readRawLongArray(length);
            case "double":
                return (T) readRawDoubleArray(length);
        }
    }
    final S[] array = (S[]) Array.newInstance(component, length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (component.isArray()) {
            array[i] = (S) readArray((Class<?>) component); // Thanks Icewind!
        } else {
            array[i] = (S) readMethodFor(nextID);
        }
    }
    return (T) array;
}
```